# THREE.Object3D(); spawning system

Tags: javascript, three.js

Basically I need help with spawning.

There are random blocks that go down the screen. At the moment only 1 block falls at a time, then another re spawns.

I would like the random blocks to spawn every 2 seconds instead of only 1 random block spawning at a time

Any help?

Heres my Codepen so you can see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Qwpqex

```
var callSpawn = setInterval(function(){
    if (RandomBlock.position.x < paddle.position.x*2.5) {  
        spawning();
        newBlock = false;
    }
},50);

function spawning() 
{
    shapes = [LeftBlock, RightBlock, middleRightBlock, middleLeftBlock, middleBlock];
    var shape = shapes[Math.floor(Math.random()*shapes.length)];
    RandomBlock = new THREE.Object3D();
    RandomBlock.add(shape);
    scene.add(RandomBlock);
    hit = false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply changing your function within your setInterval will make a block spawn every 2 seconds.
eg.

```
var callSpawn = setInterval(function(){
     spawning();
    }
},2000);
```

But then you will need to store these blocks inside an array, rather than the RandomBlock variable, and then make all the other code which manipulates the RandomBlock variable iterate through this array.

Comment: `function spawning() 
{
    
    scene.add(RandomBlock);
    hit = false; 
    
}` I took out the Randomblock code out of the function and something seems to be working. The score counts up every 2 seconds but the Randomblocks are invisible.